# Power series ring over a noetherian complete local ring of positive residue characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series, limits-colimits

Let $R$ be a noetherian complete local ring of positive residue characteristic $p>0$. A note I am reading states without proof that we have an isomorphism 
$$\varprojlim_{\nu}R[X]/\left((X+1)^{p^{\nu}}-1\right)\cong R[[X]]$$
This is allegedly a well-known isomorphism, and it holds because the residue characteristic is $p$.

I must admit that I am not really good at manipulating projective limits yet, and I'm a little at loss of idea in order to prove that such an isomorphism hold. Would anybody know what the strategy would be to prove this?

Comment: $\displaystyle\varprojlim_{\nu}R/\mathfrak{m}^n[X]/\left((X+1)^{p^{\nu}}-1\right)\cong R/\mathfrak{m}^n[[X]]$ seems much more obvious because the binomial expansion simplifies in characteristic (dividing) $p^n$, and the claim would reduce to $\displaystyle\varprojlim_n\varprojlim_{\nu}R/\mathfrak{m}^n[X]/\left((X+1)^{p^{\nu}}-1\right)=\varprojlim_{\nu}\varprojlim_n R/\mathfrak{m}^n[X]/\left((X+1)^{p^{\nu}}-1\right)$.

Comment: @reuns I see, that is a nice observation ! Is it obvious that $\varprojlim_{\nu}R/\mathfrak m^n[X]/(X^{p^{\nu}})$ is the same as $R/\mathfrak m^n [[X]]$, as not every quotient defining the power serie ring as a colimit appears in the LHS ? Then, as for the last identity we should prove, is there some general argument allowing us to swap colimits ?